# mysql syntax error in declaration of json variable

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to define a function in mysql (mysql-server version 8.0) like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myVeryCoolFunc ( json1 JSON, json2 JSON )
RETURNS JSON
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

   DECLARE abc JSON;
   DECLARE foo INT;
   DECLARE bar INT;
...
```

but it fails with the message

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

In other words: Somehow "declare abc JSON;" contains a syntax error. I just can't figure out why.

Additionally, I only get this when I try to use the mysql console or the mysql command with "--execute=...", not when I use my IDE (PyCharm).

Any help with this is greatly appreciated as I'm really losing my mind over this.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

You have to change the delimiter before defining a function with ";" in it:

e.g.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION myfunc (...)
...
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```